# View carousel image in browser without need to scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

```
> `  .carousel-inner {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60%; /* this sets carousel aspect ratio (4:1 here)50% adjust if image 
gets cut off */
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute !important; /* Bootstrap is insistent */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-item img {
  height: 100%; /* Bootstrap handles width already */
  object-fit: contain; /* or 'contain',cover,fill,scale-down,none are examples if you 
want stretch instead of crop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit 
*/
 }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;

<div class="container"> 
  <div id="carouselExampleAutoplaying" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner ">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="images/_1_early_history_and_stamp_1.jpg"  class="d-block w-100" 
      alt="books_photo">
     </div>
       </div> 

`
```

I defined the carousel image in a CSS function.  Code works however the picture is showing too large on the browser thus causing the need to move the scroll bar up and down.  Is there a way to make the image fit without scrolling?  Would I need to make the adjustments at each image based on the height and width?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but if in this case the image inside the carousel is showing the scroll, you can use a max height for the carousel and the `object-fit:cover` (you can check which is the best value for you) property in the image.
Important: the container div need property `overflow: hidden`

```css
.box{
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
  max-height: 50px;
  height:100%;
  ho
}
.carousel {
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  max-height: 150px;
  height: 90%;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-item img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
 }
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="container"> 
  <div id="carouselExampleAutoplaying" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner ">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400"  class="d-block w-100" alt="books_photo" />
     </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```